# XSL choose, when, otherwise use?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a possible way to go about the following:

You can have two columns, one titled 'sign' the other 'post'. But to only show what one is actually in use? (if you have 400 customers, then those who signed have a `<th>` saying Sigh Via etc where as if they received by post then the PostID and other `<th>` appears in the table).

I was using this method:

```
      <th> Sign Via</th>
      <th> Sign Name</th>
      <th> Sign Address</th>
      <th> Sign City</th>

       <xsl:for-each select="delivery/sign">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignVia"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignAddress"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignCity"/></td></xsl:for-each>

      <th> Post ID</th>
      <th> Post Date</th>
      <th> Post Address</th>

    <xsl:for-each select="delivery/post">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postAddress"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I attempted to add in an XSL choose statement:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="PostID">
       <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postAddress"/>
        </td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<td><xsl:value-of select="SignVia"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignAddress"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignCity"/></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:otherwise>
```

I am extremely new to XSL and XML and using W3 tutorials to get me through each stage, however I think I am missing something as I can't find a way to do this whilst using

I am hoping the end result will have something like below (I am unable to post images as I am new).
Expected result:

one table.
table contains numerous pieces of information about the product, and finally narrows down to how the customer will receive this item.
Table will include Customer details (Address etc), Order information and product specification (all of which successfully entered). But it seems when I upload it shows the information PLUS the extra 'header'.

example:
Customer one has signed for their item, it comes up 'signvia  signname' etc. But also above it clings 'postID, postDate' even though they are empty.

Cheers in advance.

Edited:
Remainder of XSL:

```
      <body>
            <th> Customer Name</th>
            <th> Number</th>
            <th>Address</th>

        <xsl:for-each select="customer">
          <tr style="color:black; background: #eee;">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="CustomerName"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Number"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Address"/></td>
       </tr>



          <th> Post ID</th>
      <th>Post Date</th>
      <th> Post Address</th>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="PostID">
       <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="postAddress"/>
        </td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<th> Sign Name</th>
      <th> Sign Address</th>
      <th> Sign City</th>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignAddress"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignCity"/></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:otherwise>




        <th> ProductN</th>
        <th> Quan</th>
        <th> Unit </th>
        <th> Disc </th>

    <xsl:for-each select="productStock/product">      
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ProductN"/></td>  
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quan"/></td>   
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Amoun"/></td>    
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Reas"/></td>       



  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you post a small example of the input + the expected result of the example? --

Comment: did you enclose your attempt in double foreach like this: <xsl:for-each select="delivery/sign"><xsl:for-each select="delivery/post">//yourattempt// </xsl:for-each> </xsl:for-each>

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated, sorry if my explanation is too far fetched. I couldn't upload an image!

Comment: @noob I don't believe I did.

Comment: @Coli-Eza An image would be useless here; post some **code** that we can copy and try to reproduce your issue with.

Comment: Is my request for an example of the XML input and of the expected result somehow not clear? Perhaps this can make it clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To be fair @michael.hor257k as someone who has clearly stated they are new to XML - not stating you want the XML is not stating what you want exactly.

Comment: What's fair is fair ... so now you know that XML is the input to the process of XSL transformation - and the output can be XML, HTML (as in your case) or plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not a Xml guru but some what I've a feeling that your program flow is wrong. Try this:

```
      <xsl:if test="customer/PostID">
            <xsl:for-each select="delivery/post">
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="postID"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="postDate"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="postAddress"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(customer/PostID)">
        <xsl:for-each select="delivery/sign">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SignVia"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="SignName"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="SignAddress"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="SignCity"/></td>
         </xsl:for-each>          
     </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Somehow by doing this it has removed any 'post' information and only showing one customer Signing. @noob

Comment: the only thing that changes is that the 'sign' section has headers still but no content :(

Comment: We don't see much of the code (no template match), let alone an input sample. All bets are off as long as the OP does not give complete information.

Comment: @Coli-Eza In my desperate attempt to help you I've made one last edit (making my own assumption about your XML). Try it and if it doesn't work all the best